# Css no se carga al registrar otra url

Tags: php, mvc

Buen día. Soy nuevo en stack overflow tengo un problema con los archivos css y js, el caso es que los archivos css y js si se cargar bien pero si registro otra URL por ejemplo `$router->Get("/home/traveler",[PaguesContrler::class,"Traveler"]);` Los css no se cargar, pero si lo dejo `$router->Get("/home",[PaguesContrler::class,"Home"]);` los css si se cargan perfectamenro.
Es como si accedieran a archivos de diferente niveles de carpetas, utilizo MVC y por supuesto des del controlador llamo las vistas.

Comment: Pero cada archivo llama a sus CSS y JS, osea **/home** me imagino que lee el index o lo que sea y en ese index tu has llamado los CSS. Si quieres usar **/home/traveler** que es otra carpeta o archivo debes volver a llamarlos en esa nueva ruta, a no ser que uses una misma plantilla para todo y en esa plantilla previamente cargues los recursos. No se si yo entendí mal o tu no has explicado bien...

Comment: Hola si entiendo tu respuesta, el caso es que uso una sola plantilla donde cargo cada una de los elementos, en esa plantilla cargo los css y los js.

Comment: Ya vio el código fuente de la pagina para ver la ruta que tiene la plantilla en la segunda página? 

Por cierto **/Home** no debería estar antes que **/home/traveler**??

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: El problema es que los archivos css  no se cargar cuando agre a la URL otro separador "/" ejemplo *localhost:3000/home* <= desde esta URL el css se carga, pero si pongo *localhost:3000/home/traveler* <= desde esta otra es donde los css ya no se cargan, el controlador debuelve una plantilla cuando sele solicitan esas URL una plantilla donde se cargas los demás elementos